# FastAPI receives Basic Auth headers instead of Bearer

Tags: python, fastapi, bearer-token, starlette

I'm encountering an intermittent issue with my FastAPI application where the Authorization headers switch from Bearer token to Basic auth without any changes to the request being made. This issue resolves itself without any clear intervention, making it particularly perplexing. The application is containerised using Docker, and I'm testing the endpoints using the auto-docs generated by FastAPI.

Here is the code I am using to verify the user access token:

```
from fastapi import HTTPException, Depends, status, Request
from fastapi.security import HTTPAuthorizationCredentials, HTTPBearer
from jose import jwt, JWTError, ExpiredSignatureError
from starlette.datastructures import Secret

from common.settings import ACCESS_SECRET_KEY, HASHING_ALGORITHM

# Initialization of HTTPBearer for security
security = HTTPBearer()


# Exception for invalid user credentials
INVALID_USER_HTTP_EXCEPTION = HTTPException(
    status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
    detail="Could not validate credentials.",
    headers={"WWW-Authenticate": "Bearer"},
)

def decode_jwt_token(token: str, secret_key: Secret) -> dict:
    """Decodes a JWT token using the provided secret key.

    This function validates a JWT token's structure and ensures it hasn't expired.
    It distinguishes between tracking tokens and access/refresh tokens, applying
    specific validations for each.

    Args:
        token: The JWT token to be decoded.
        secret_key: The secret key used for decoding the token.

    Returns:
        The decoded token payload as a dictionary.

    Raises:
        HTTPException: For invalid tokens, expired tokens, or tokens with missing fields.
    """
    try:
        payload = jwt.decode(token, key=str(secret_key), algorithms=[HASHING_ALGORITHM])
        token_type = payload.get('token_type')

        if token_type not in ('tracking', 'access', 'refresh'):
            raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST, detail="Invalid token type.")

        if token_type == 'tracking' and (not payload.get('contact_id') or not payload.get('sequence_id')):
            raise INVALID_USER_HTTP_EXCEPTION

        if token_type in ('access', 'refresh') and not payload.get("sub"):
            raise INVALID_USER_HTTP_EXCEPTION

        return payload
    except ExpiredSignatureError:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=440, detail="Token has expired. Log-in again.", headers={"WWW-Authenticate": "Bearer"})
    except JWTError as e:
        _logger.info(f"JWTError: {e}")
        raise INVALID_USER_HTTP_EXCEPTION


def verify_access_token(authorization: HTTPAuthorizationCredentials = Depends(security)) -> str:
    """Verifies an access token and retrieves the user's email.

    Decodes the access token from the authorization header to ensure it is valid
    and extracts the user's email address from it.

    Args:
        authorization: The authorization credentials containing the JWT token.

    Returns:
        The user's email address extracted from the token.

    Raises:
        HTTPException: If the token is invalid or if the email is missing.
    """
    token = authorization.credentials
    payload = decode_jwt_token(token=token, secret_key=ACCESS_SECRET_KEY)
    email = payload.get("sub")

    if email is None:
        raise INVALID_USER_HTTP_EXCEPTION

    return email
```

Running the above, I kept receiving a 403 response with the message "Invalid authentication credentials". This is the response that FastAPI automatically returns when the authorization scheme of the request Header is not equal to `"bearer"`.

When sending a `GET` request to my FastAPI endpoint with a `Bearer` token in the `Authorization` header, the application sometimes logs the `Authorization` header as `Basic` auth instead. This issue appears randomly and resolves itself after some time. Below are the details of the `curl` command and the logs from two different attempts:

```
curl -X 'GET' \
  'http://localhost/users/' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer <token>'
```

###### First Attempt Log (Issue Present):

```
2024-03-26 10:02:56

Headers: Headers(
{
    "host": "localhost",
    "authorization": "Basic YWRtaW...",
    "sec-fetch-site": "same-origin",
    "accept-language": "en-GB,en;q=0.9",
    "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate",
    "sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
    "accept": "application/json",
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/16.6 Safari/605.1.15",
    "connection": "keep-alive",
    "referer": "http://localhost/docs",
    "cookie": "session=eyJzdGF0ZSI6I...",
    "sec-fetch-dest": "empty",
}
)
```

###### Second Attempt Log (Issue Resolved, 17 minutes later):

```
2024-03-26 10:19:12

Headers: Headers(
{
    "host": "localhost",
    "authorization": "Bearer <token>",
    "sec-fetch-site": "same-origin",
    "accept-language": "en-GB,en;q=0.9",
    "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate",
    "sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
    "accept": "application/json",
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/16.6 Safari/605.1.15",
    "connection": "keep-alive",
    "referer": "http://localhost/docs",
    "cookie": "session=eyJzdGF0ZS...",
    "sec-fetch-dest": "empty",
}
)
```

Attempts to Diagnose/Resolve the Issue:

- Ensured no caching proxies or layers are interfering with the requests.
- Checked Docker container and network configurations for potential misconfigurations.
- Reviewed FastAPI and related dependencies for updates or known issues.

Are there known issues with FastAPI's `HTTPBearer` class that might cause this intermittent recognition of `Bearer` vs. `Basic` auth headers? How might I go about fixing this issue?

Comment: Are you sure that the `Basic` entry authentication is actually coming from your curl request and not being logged because the swagger UI attempts to check something in the background - because you have a tab open with the UI or something similar? What does the other headers say when those requests happen?

Comment: Thank you for your interest in my question! I'm uncertain if the Swagger UI is trying to verify something – do you know how I might be able to check that? Additionally, both requests originated from the /docs endpoint, which leads me to doubt that's the root of the problem, particularly because this issue also occurs when requests are made from different sources.

I've updated my question to include all headers from these requests for further clarity.

Comment: They're both being made by your browser at least, and not by the `curl` command you've included, so be aware of that red herring (since they have the user agent set to reflect Safari). I'd start by looking at the network requests in Safari's developer tools to see which requests your doc api is being made, and I'd verify the context of the requests when being made from other sources - i.e. what is being requested and by whom; it could be related to the library you're using:

Comment: Also make sure that you haven't mistyped an URL somewhere, effectively making a request for `http://foo@hostname` or something similar - this would cause a request being sent with HTTP basic authorization by default (`http://user:pass@hostname/path` is the common shortcut form in URLs).

Comment: @MatsLindh thanks for your comments. I will investigate the things you have suggested! It's especially hard to debug as the issue seems to just resolve itself after a while

Comment: An initial guess is that a tab is being put to sleep or no-one hits that exact place where a username/password has been included inadvertently (tip: decode the string behind `Basic` with a base64 decode and see what it is - then if it seems unknown grep for the decoded string in your code base).